# dynamic cast Entities A good design?

Tags: c++

For my game,

Everything inherits from Entity, then other things like Player, PhysicsObject, etc, inherit from Entity. The physics engine sends collision callbacks which has an Entity* to the B that A collided on. Then, lets say A is a Bullet, A tries to  cast the entity as a player, if it succeeds, it reduces the player's health.

Is this a good design?

Thanks

Comment: It's so confusing, I never know where to post :(

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I believe that messaging system is somehow better suits your "world".

```
Entity* target = ...;
bool    handled = target->send(M_COLLIDE, ...);
```

In this case you will not need neither dynamic casts nor to check result of dynamic cast.

**Update**, here is an example:

```
target->send(M_COLLECT, pMushroom);
...

Person::handle(uint message, Entity* the_thing)
{
  switch(message) 
  {
    case M_COLLECT: this->things.push( the_thing ); 
                    the_thing->send(M_COLLECTED_BY, this); break;
  }
}
```

`Entity::handle(uint message, Entity* the_thing)` implementation can be wrapped into
MSG_MAP_START, MSG_MAP_END and HANDLE_MSG(msg) macros so your code will look like:

```
MSG_MAP_START

   HANDLE_MSG(M_COLLECT)
   {
     this->things.push( the_thing ); 
     the_thing->send(M_COLLECTED_BY, this);
   }
   HANDLE_MSG(M_COLLECTED_BY) 
   {
     ...
   }
   ...
MSG_MAP_END
```

Many variations of this are possible.

By the way Objective-C has this kind of messaging built-in into the language. With extremely ugly notation but still.

Comment: How does the bullet set the health then?

Comment: `bool    handled = target->send(M_HIT_BY, pBullet);`
Each target handles M_HIT_BY differently. Player for example decrements health counter. 

General idea of messaging is that you have system of loosely coupled types. If tomorrow you will need something like M_CHARMED_BY you will need to change only Belle class (sender) and, say, Player (potential receiver). All other classes and places in code don't need to be changed.

Comment: What about if the player needs to pick up an item, so how is the case of passing data handled? (aside from, casting a pointer)

Comment: Thanks, though what I meant is, what if the player needs a casted version of an Entity (like Weapon), is it then appropriate to dynamic cast?